# Playing around with Eclipse features - Project files are now hidden?

Tags: java, eclipse, file, project

I don't even remember how, but somehow I managed to make all of my project's source files hidden in Eclipse's Package and Project Explorer panels.  Go figure.

'Show Filtered Children (alt+click)' temporarily reveals the files, and only in Package Explorer can I double-click to reopen them from this view.  They go back into hiding after I select another item, though.  Plus, now I'm getting other annoyances, such as all of the folded non-hidden trees altogether expanding when I click on any item, and the entire file folder tree of my project now being shown in these panels (including my .svn subversion folders... which shouldn't be any of Eclipse's business, presently).

Long story short, my Package/Project Explorers' just blew up on me, and I want to know how to fix this.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the folder that you have the project files stored inside of, are they set to hidden?

Also you can try reseting your workstation.Go to window then reset perspective.

I hope that helps it may not.

Comment: 'Reset perspective' cleaned things up a bit.  Thanks.  I still can't get to my hidden source files, though.  They're not actually hidden in the file system, either.

Comment: Okay, somehow I've managed to make them visible again.  I guess that settles my problem, then.

Answer (score 7):

I've had the same issue.

It turned out that I accidentally clicked "Focus on Active Tasks" - it's the third option from the left in the Package Explorer window (in the top-right corner).

Comment: Thanks you have saved me. I think its mylyn plugin that activate this features.

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to do a clean restart: http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/platform-core/documents/3.1/debug.html